# Writing data on a subsequent row in excel file using Groovy

Tags: excel, groovy, soapui

I am trying to create a script that will write data to an excel file after I execute a Test Case in SoapUI and write a subsequent row of data in the same file after I execute another test of the same type. I am trying with a script that looks like this:

```
def count = context.expand('${Data#Count}')
def value = context.expand('${Data#Value}')

def row = count -1



WritableWorkbook workbook1 = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("Path.xls"))
WritableSheet sheet1 = workbook1.createSheet("Worksheet Number 1", 0)

log.info(sheet1.isHidden())
Label label_0 = new Label(0, ('${count}'), value)

sheet1.addCell(label_0)

workbook1.write()
workbook1.close()
```

The problem is that when I try to use the **count** value to specify the row the system returns an error. Can you tell me how I can define the row number in order to write each different set of data on a subsequent row?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which error? looks like you need to change to: Label label_0 = new Label(0, count, value)

Comment: If I try it like this **Label label_0 = new Label(0, count, value)** I am getting the following error: **groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: jxl.write.Label(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)** ... it seems that it doesn't like that I am putting string instead of integer for rows ...

Comment: So Label has public Label(int c, int r, String cont) constructor that means that your count variable is string instead of int. change count to count.toInteger()

Comment: Thank you :) The script works now. 

Unfortunately, now instead of writing each value from each subsequent test case on a subsequent row in the excel workbook it is replacing the A1 column with the newest latest value. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: Not sure. But looks like you need to use existing sheet instead of create new one for each test case. Something like: Sheet sheet = workbook1.getSheetAt(0)

Comment: If I try it like this :
`WritableWorkbook workbook1 = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("Path.xls"))
WritableSheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheetAt(0)` I am getting an error **Cannot cast object 'jxl.read.biff.WorkbookParser@18d428dc' with class 'jxl.read.biff.WorkbookParser' to class 'jxl.write.WritableWorkbook** , somehow this is not reading the created file.

Comment: try: WritableSheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheets()?.getAt(0); if(!sheet1){ sheet1 = workbook1.createSheet("Worksheet Number 1", 0)}

Comment: I was able to get it work like this :
`Workbook existingWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("Path.xls"));
WritableWorkbook workbookCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("Path.xls"), existingWorkbook);`

but then I was facing an issue that is probably a common one - if I open the file to view the recorded values, close it and then run again the test in order to add more records or replace existing one the excel file corrupts, goes to size 0 KB and it can't be opened. Any chance to know how I can deal with these problem ? :/

Comment: Sorry, I dont know)